# How do I set the contents of a label and have it reset to string.empty after a period of 5 seconds in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I've no real idea how to do this and I have tried messing with a timer but to no avail so far.

So what am I trying to do?

I have a label that is blank.  When a certain event is triggered I want the label to say "Competition successfully setup" for a period of 5 seconds after which I want it to return to being blank.

Surely this can be done??  Can it?  I have played around with a timer but I seem to be well off the mark.

Any help would be most welcome.  My feeble attempt is below.

```
private void UpdateLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var timer = new Timer()
                {
                    Interval = 5000,
                };
            timer.Tick += (s, evt) =>
                  lblCompetitionSetupSuccess.Text = "Competition successfully setup";

            timer.Start();

            lblCompetitionSetupSuccess.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: what you got when you run this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the other way around:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "I will vanish in 5 sec";

        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Tick += (o, args) => label1.Text = "";
        timer.Start();
    }
```

First set the label to whatever text you want it to display for 5 sec

```
        label1.Text = "I will vanish in 5 sec";
```

Then setup your timer so that on timer elapsed it will remove the text

```
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Tick += (o, args) => label1.Text = "";
        timer.Start();
```

If you want the timer to stop after the first timer elapse:

```
        timer.Tick += (o, args) =>
            {
                label1.Text = "";
                timer.Enabled = false;
            };
```

Comment: Could the timer be stopped when the label is cleaned? Otherwise it will continue executing forever even if there's nothing going on, right?

Comment: Does it need to be enabled again when restarting?

Comment: won't "the next time" be when you call update label again? because then you instantiate a new timer and start from scratch again. so in that case, no

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've got it now.

Comment: Rather than stop the timer, just set auto reset to false when you create it.

Comment: he's using `System.Windows.Forms`, not `System.Timers.Timer` (note the `Tick` property instead of the `Elapsed` property that `System.Timers.Timer` contains

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class, which calls the tick event on the UI thread.